# Running Selenium with IE11 for several minutes results in the browser freezing

Tags: selenium, capybara

When running several tests synchronously using Selenium with IE, after about 10 minutes the browser starts to freeze. The browser will not render pages properly or respond at all. I can only diagnose that when these symptoms occur, the Memory reaches about 1.7G and hovers around there. I use Capybara so after every test, on average about every 30 seconds, it will reset the session. This issue does not occur when I use Firefox or Chrome.

Does anyone have any thoughts? I could try figuring out why it stops at 1.6G, but I imagine I'd hit the same issue once hit what ever new cap is set. I could also restart the process every few tests, but that would slow the test run down dramatically.

Configuration:

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Selenium grid: v2.46.0
- IEDriver: 32-bit
- v2.46.0.0 (Tried using 64 bit but sending keys went very slow)
- Browser: IE11

Thanks in advance for thoughts you might have.

Comment: Are you executing IE instances in parallel.I mean at the moment how many ie drivers will be running

Comment: I'm just using one IE instance and driver.

Comment: this is happening for all webpages or your application only.Have you tested by running some sample flows like automating simple applications..

Comment: That's a good idea, I have not, I'll try that.

Comment: Can you reproduce it manually?

Comment: We are unable to reproduce it manually, the app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem and noticed that every character typed using `sendKeys()` consumes around 2 MB (!) in IE. We now restart the driver every 10 tests, which works for us.

Note: you could try replacing `webElement.sendKeys` with a Windows API call like `SendInput` and see if the problem in IE still remains.

Comment: Thanks, that's great info, I'll probably end up just doing that.